# Search for a line of text (as search criteria) and replace a certain string of digits in that line?

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace, autolisp

I have a rather extensive autolisp file (roughly 4000 lines) that writes a big comma-delimited list of item numbers and their descriptions to a file. here's an example (they all look the same as this, save for the number and description)

```
>(write-line (strcat "0203," (itoa 1-2x4x8) ",    PCS   2x4x 92 5/8 STUD GRADE FIR" ) file)
```

the "0203," is the item number and the "2x4x 92 5/8 STUD GRADE FIR" is the description, dont mind the commas or PCS (stands for "pieces"), they're irrelevant. what matters is I need to change that item number to match the new list. this is where i believe regular expressions might help but I'm having trouble finding out.

Basically, I need to search the file for a description (like the example above) and replace the 4 digit number with a new number. can regular or extended expressions do that? (or perhaps something else) and just to be clear

The number will always be 4 digits located exactly as shown, the description will only ever occur once in the file (they are exact), the description and the associated number i need to replace will always be on the same line.

please help :)

Comment: But with what would you like to replace the number?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure regex is going to help you with this.  Regex is most usefull if you search for lines with recurring pattern(s) and optionally replace a pattern with fixed text or the value matched by another pattern on the line.

In my understanding of what you describe, you are looking for fixed text, different in each line, and want to replace a part of the line with a number related one-to-one with the search text.  This is quite a different use case, you need to iterate for each search text and have another table which links the search text and the new number.

In my view, you would need to create a regex for each of your search texts, and a substitution pattern for the old to new number something like (in a vi-kind of command):

```
s!\d+,(.*2x4x 92 5/8 STUD GRADE FIR)!1234,\2!
```

This matches a 4 digit number and comma, followed by stuff and your search text.  The substitution replaces this whole thing with the 'new' number, the comma and the matched capturing group.
But creating these regex lines is essentially more work then doing the replacement by hand in the file...